# Fast way to get process owners in .NET

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke

I have the following .NET code that reaches out to the `OpenProcessToken` Win32 API to retrieve the owner names of all processes on the system:

```cs
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Test
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, uint DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
    
    private const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;

    public static List<List<String>> GetProcessWithUsers() 
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        var result = new List<List<string>>();
        foreach (var proc in processes)
        {
            result.Add(new List<string> { proc.ProcessName, GetProcessUser(proc) });
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static string GetProcessUser(Process process)
    {
        IntPtr tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TOKEN_QUERY, out tokenHandle);
            WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
            return wi.Name;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `Test.GetProcessWithUsers()` (e.g. in LinqPad) takes almost 2 seconds for the 280 processes on my system.

I don't consider this an acceptable amount of time for this task.

`Process.GetProcesses()` is snappy, `new WindowsIdentity()`'s contribution is negligible, so what's the hold-up with `OpenProcessToken()`? Are there alternative Win32 API functions that would be faster?

Comment: Process.Handle is the issue (causes access denied). Should be much faster if you run as admin. You could write the whole thing using P/Invoke to avoid this if you're after performance

Comment: @SimonMourier I can't run it as admin, that's the thing.

Comment: I understand but is it faster? If yes, then rewrite using full P/Invoke

Comment: @SimonMourier As admin it goes down to ~350 ms. Faster, but still on the slow side for mere 280 iterations. Maybe `OpenProcessToken` simply is the wrong thing to use?

Comment: On My PC (I9-9900K 3.6GHz) as admin is 170ms for 293 process. I doubt you'll get much under that.

Comment: `OpenProcessToken` is ok and not create any problems or slowdown if you have process handle with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access. however - what sense / final target collect owner sids ?

Comment: Here is a version that should be faster (full p/invoke) https://pastebin.com/raw/ae5Eg9iP

Comment: @SimonMourier This definititely *is* faster. We are now at 90 ms for all processes, and for what I'm trying to do, `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` is probably enough.

Comment: @RbMm In this case, I'm trying to generate a list of my own processes (as a non-admin user). Since `Process.GetProcesses()` gets *all* processes, I needed something to filter it down.

Comment: *list of my own processes* - this is what/what sense in it (not direct related to your question until)

Comment: @RbMm In this case, yes. I have been searching for a couple of days now how to do this faster in .NET, and have turned up nothing. I'm not an expert in Win32 API programming by any stretch of the imagination, I can only go by what examples are available. And all of them are slow.

Comment: @SimonMourier I can extend this on my own from this point on - if you post your code as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: i am expert in win32 native but not in .NET. not view any problems in enumerate all processes and open it token, query token owner sid ( default owner SID that will be applied to newly created objects). but i not understand sense of this (query owner sid)

Comment: @RbMm In this particular instance, it's merely for figuring out *"is this an own process, or someone else's"*, for the purpose of filtering down the full list of processes, and ultimately driving a list box. I don't care about processes I don't own, so *any* method to make that distinction would be good enough for what I am trying to do.  But more generally speaking, I was wondering why the `OpenProcessToken` call was so slow. An "access denied" result should be faster, shouldn't it?

Comment: i think you wrong understand what is `TOKEN_OWNER` .. - i be use some another criteria for filter process list. this of course another question, but i sure you must based not on this (owner sid) . about *why the OpenProcessToken call was so slow* - here you wrong - this api not slow and you in any way can not control how fast it will be executed. in all current code is slow - slow point not in this call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234629/discussion-between-tomalak-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time used seems to be caused by .NET's `Process` class (Access Denied exception legitimately thrown, etc.), so here is a full P/Invoke version that doesn't use it but uses the native [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot):

```
[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(int dwFlags, int th32ProcessID);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool Process32First(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool Process32Next(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private struct PROCESSENTRY32
{
    public int dwSize;
    public int cntUsage;
    public int th32ProcessID;
    public IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
    public int th32ModuleID;
    public int cntThreads;
    public int th32ParentProcessID;
    public int pcPriClassBase;
    public int dwFlags;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szExeFile;
}

public static List<List<string>> GetProcessWithUsers()
{
    var result = new List<List<string>>();
    const int TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 2;
    var snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    var entry = new PROCESSENTRY32();
    entry.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf<PROCESSENTRY32>();
    if (Process32First(snap, ref entry))
    {
        do
        {
            const int PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x00001000;
            var handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, entry.th32ProcessID);
            result.Add(new List<string> { entry.szExeFile, GetProcessUser(handle) });
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(handle);
            }
        }
        while (Process32Next(snap, ref entry));
    }
    CloseHandle(snap);
    return result;
}

public static string GetProcessUser(IntPtr handle)
{
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return null;

    const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    if (!OpenProcessToken(handle, TOKEN_QUERY, out var tokenHandle))
        return null;

    var wi = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
    CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
    return wi.Name;
}
```

On my PC, I've been down from 1500 ms to 30 ms (x50).

Comment: `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` ( particularly `Process32Next`) very bad design and slow compare use `NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation..)`. if want maximum speed of course better use `NtQuerySystemInformation`

Comment: There's a lot of missing error checking and `finally` blocks here

Comment: @Charlieface - No, it's not missing, I'm not interested by error details, I'm just dumping what I can. As for finally there are not many throws possible here (maybe in WindowsIdentity constructor ok), it's interop code. Anyway, error checking wasn't the question.

Comment: @RbMm - I know, it was added for Windows 95 compat back then because NtQuerySystemInformation was undoc'd. But I didn't designed it myself, it's public and less work to interop from my point of view, I don't live here. You should try, see what are the gains if any in this .NET context and post another answer.

Comment: I can add the error checking and the finally clauses, I think. "Dumping what I can" is good enough for my use case.

Comment: i simply note that `NtQuerySystemInformation` will be faster (i not think that your solution bad, visa versa. simply this will be yet faster). why `Process32Next` not good enough ? because it internally copied data (from `NtQuerySystemInformation`) to section and on every call to `Process32First/Process32Next` it map and unmap this section and copy data to user buffer. this map/unmap main point of slowdown. also `Process32Next` by some unknown reason drop some infrormation which returned by original `SystemProcessInformation` (terminal session id)